# maps windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps, bing-maps, nokia, bing

I am trying to make an application for windows phone 8 that could track current location of user and gives a route from current location to desired destination location.

With existing maps feature (bing, Nokia maps) it is not possible to track the location areas for Karachi Pakistan by their respective names. For example, if I want to get the route from pizza hut, Karachi to dolmen mall, Karachi, it will never show a route since the areas are not marked in the map.

This problem doesn't occur for people living in the US I suppose, since I saw many tutorials where exact locations are shown by just typing in the area names in the search bar (as for Redmond and Chicago). What should we, the users of elsewhere do.... while if we see Google maps, all areas even of Karachi, Pakistan are marked.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

In Bing Maps, if you have two coordinates that are on roads that are drawn on Bing Maps you can get a route between them anywhere in the world. WP8 uses just Nokia data which is only one of several data providers used by Bing Maps. You can use the Bing Maps REST services to route between any two coordinates that are on roads in the world, including Pakistan. Here is some information about the Bing Maps REST routing service:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701705.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870778.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Bing Maps are very powerful and easy to implement but unfortunately they are not supported in Pakistan. Due to restriction you are not able to find route between two geo location point or places. But Microsoft promised to give its support in Pakistan very soon as they are working on it as well.

The link given below will show you the restriction of bing maps in different regions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj670541.aspx

I have written a blog post in which I have drawn a route between two location points but it will not work for you as I already told you.

http://dev-bingmaps.blogspot.com/

Now there is one solution in from which you can find route that is to use google maps.

Comment: Try posting some actual details in your answer rather than just links. Links have a nasty tendency to disappear later in the future.

Comment: Ok Thanks for you suggestion but one of the link is of my own blog.

Comment: Not sure where you are sourcing your information about the future of Bing Maps. But if it is true its likely not something you should be sharing unless its public knowledge.

Comment: Also, those documented restrictions are for the Windows Store (windows 8/8.1) control and is unrelated to the WP8 control.